# Facing Error while including ASG details in NSG rules using Terraform in azure

Tags: azure, terraform-provider-azure

I am trying to implement NSG rules  using terraform and tryin to include ASG id in the rule. While doing terrafomr plan ut gives me the following error. Also I have the ASG already created in azure portal already which i a, trying to include in the rule using Data Block.[image]

```html
destination_application_security_group_ids = ["data,azurerm_application_security_group.id"]
```

Can please someone help with this error
The given value is not suitable for module.Nsg.var.nsg_rules declared at modules\Nsg\nsg_variables.tf:20,1-21: element 1: attribute
│ "destination_application_security_group_ids" is required.

Comment: Posts on stackoverflow get nothing from me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried to provision NSG for ASG using Terraform, and I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error mentioned occurred when you were trying to create or update the NSG rule. It states that when defining your security rule in Terraform you must provide only **one exact value** among the 3 mentioned below in your NSG rule.

1. `DestinationAddressPrefixes`
2. `DestinationAddressPrefix`
3. `DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups`

Using any two or three simultaneously in the rule will lead you to the error mentioned.

There is also an error in syntax in the data module declaration mentioned in the error.

Since you want to link ASG with NSG and its rule I was using the following configuration as per your requirement.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
    provider "azurerm" {
      features {}
    }
    
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
        name = "demorgvkrg"
    }
    
    data "azurerm_application_security_group" "example" {
      name                = "examplevk-asg"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    
    
    resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "example" {
      name                = "acceptanceTestSecurityGroupvk1"
      location            = "east us"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "example" {
      name                        = "test123"
      priority                    = 1001
      direction                   = "Outbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      protocol                    = "Tcp"
      source_port_range           = "*"
      destination_port_range      = "80"
      source_address_prefix       = "*"
      resource_group_name         = "demorgvkrg"
      network_security_group_name = "acceptanceTestSecurityGroupvk1"
      destination_application_security_group_ids = [data.azurerm_application_security_group.example.id]
}
```

**Output:**

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: hi thankyou for the response. i tried not use all three properties which is DestinationAddressPrefixes
DestinationAddressPrefix
DestinationApplicationSecurityGroups all together but still i am facing issue. Also By creating an individial resource just for nsg rules and tthen trying to put asg there is working for me but i want to know why doesnt it work usng data block for importing existing asg in the variables where i have put all my nsg rules

Comment: @SarahPotrick Please try to Remove the destination_address_prefix attribute from your azurerm_network_security_rule definition.
Ensure you only use destination_application_security_group_ids to specify the application security groups for the destination.
This will work as you expected.

Comment: Thankyou so much it worked